# Set expiration date for cookie from different domain

Tags: cookies

Is there any way I can set Cookie expiration date from other page - i want to delete the cookie across domain. E.g. there are two domains: first.com, second.com . From second.com i want to set expiration date for cookie from first.com. I don't have an access to first.com.

Comment: What are your actual domain names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. It's a security policy of the browser.

Imagine if any domain could spy on the cookies set by an other domain!